# Reading sensor data from two phones simultaneously in Matlab

Tags: android, ios, matlab, mobile-devices

I want to connect two or more mobile devices to Matlab. Right now I am able to connect to both my android phone and iphone; however, I am unable to distinguish between them. I use this code to connect:

connector on Password;

m = mobiledev;

Is there any way I can store two 1x1 mobildev's and gather data from them simultaneously?